# Prepend city name in domain

Tags: domains, subdomain

I'm interested in creating a website that will have a city name as a prepended word for each city it is launched in, like craigslist.com does. Is that possible to do without buying a new domain for each one? Would that be common across any domain registrar?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of setup you have but if you have a dedicated server with cpanel installed, theres an option in there to make subdomains for free.

Comment: The key word here being **subdomain** (which is what craigslist uses).

Comment: @Mike This sounds like a perfectly good beginning to what would be a short and simple answer.

Comment: Had I known more about his server setup, then I could have possibly come up with an official answer.

Comment: @Mike Much of the time in situations like this, I pretend that there are a couple of common options and go with that. Since hosting with cPanel is so common, that is one option- and so I might have just pretended that was the only option generally and mention briefly others. Sometimes an answer can be short and does not have to be detailed. The shortest answer I gave was a sentence and a link. The answer was in the sentence of course- not the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating subdomains has nothing to do with the registrar, it depends on your hosting company.

Some will allow unlimited subdomains but may limit how many sites you can have.  This isn't a problem if you only have one site that they all point too and you parse the subdomain.

Some hosts restrict how many subdomains you can have.

You will need to do research based on your idea, don't forget to allow for growth in case you are successful and need to expand.